# How to access element in vector<map<first, pair<K,V>>>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, std-pair

I'm having trouble with accessing map's and pair's members within a vector container.  I tried to use for loop and vector iterator to try and access the elements inside vector but no luck.  Here is my code:

```
typedef int lep_index;
typedef double gold;
typedef double pos;
map<lep_index, pair<gold, pos>> lep;
vector <map<lep_index, pair<gold, pos>>>  leps;

//initialize lep and leps
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    lep[i - 1] = pair<gold, pos>(MILLION, i * MILLION);
    leps.push_back(lep);
}

//I can access lep's elements by doing this
for (auto &i : lep) {
            cout << i.first << ": " << i.second.first << ", " << i.second.second << endl;
        }

//but when i try with vector...
for (vector <map<lep_index, pair<gold, pos>>>::iterator it = leps.begin(); it != leps.end; it++) {
            cout << it->
        }
//I cannot use it pointer to access anything
```

I don't know what I did wrong here or the correct way to do it so hope I can get some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for (auto& map : leps) {
    for (auto& i : map) {
            cout << i.first << ": " << i.second.first
                 << ", " << i.second.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see now, so after the first loop, it represents map<first, pair<K,V>> ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your first loop just goes through the items of the vector and returns you the maps one by one. So you need another loop for each map.

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of `leps`, you will need another `for` loop.

```
for (vector <map<lep_index, pair<gold, pos>>>::iterator it = leps.begin(); it != leps.end; it++)
{
   auto& lep = *it;         // lep is a map.
   for ( auto& item : lep ) // For each item in the map.
   {
      cout << item.first << ": " << item.second.first << ", " << item.second.second << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like so:

```
std::cout << vec[0][100].first << " " << vec[0][100].second << '\n';
```

Where 0 is the first element in the vector and 100 is the key.

If you want to access every element, the `range-based for loop` is convenient:

```
for (const auto& i : vec)
    for (const auto& j : i) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << j.first << '\n';
        std::cout << "pair: " << j.second.first << " " << j.second.second << '\n';
    }
```